# Solve $3= 3^{z}.$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, exponential-function, exponentiation

I'm stuck in solving this strange and beautiful formula : $3= 3^{z}$ since it says 'Solve' and not 'Prove'

Also i really don't understand what does it means by saying $3^{z}$? Will $3^z$ form a set ?

I will be very grateful if you can help me or even give me a little hint to make a headway with this problem ...

To be clear, find all $z \in \left\{ 3 = 3^z \right\}.$

Comment: This notation makes no sense.

Comment: I assume it should be 'Prove' instead of 'Solve' since it does not contain an equality symbol

Comment: For two natural numbers $a$ and $b$ satisfying $a<b$ we know that $a\in b$.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't say solve $3=3^z$?

Comment: Yes I'm positive

Comment: What is meant that we have to show that the number $3$ is in the set {$3^z|z\in \mathbb C$} , which is the case because $z=1$ does the job.

Comment: "Solve" is clearly the wrong formulation in this case. It must be "prove".

Comment: Thanks bro, this was so helpful

Comment: [Set-theoretic definition of natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers)

Comment: Perhaps you are asked (asking) for $z$ such that $3^z=3?$

Answer (score 3):

Well, if the question is asking to find all $z$ such that

$$3^z = 3$$

Then

$$\begin{aligned}
3^z &= 3e^{2 k \pi i } \\
z \log 3  &=\log 3 + 2 k \pi i   \\
\end{aligned}$$
$$\bbox[5px, border: 1pt solid blue]{z = 1 + \frac{2 k \pi i}{\log 3}, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}.}
$$

There are infinitely many solutions, and they all lie on the line $\text{Re }z=1.$

Answer (score 0):

Since $z$ is a complex number then $z=x+iy$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

Also Since $0,1 \in \mathbb{R}$ then $z=x+iy=(1)+i(0)=1$

Thus $1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ And $3^{1}=3 \in 3^{z}$